# How to remove duplicate label from geom_text in ggplot2 for alluvial plot?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am making an alluvial plot and wanted to label the node part of the diagram with percentages.
When I use the "geom_text" function, I get duplicate labels, within one perfectly situated where I want it but the other is off to the side on the far right of the image screenshot below. How do I get rid of that duplicate on the far right?
[image]

Here is my code thus far:

```
ggplot(data = survey_3,
               aes(axis1 = leave, axis2 = stringr::str_wrap(Q58,40), y = freq)) + #add intention to leave and responses as axes 1 & 2 & the y-axis as frequency
  geom_alluvium(aes(fill = Q58)) + #response is the fill of the alluvial plot band
  geom_stratum() +
  scale_x_discrete(limits=c("leave", "Q58"), expand=c(0.1, 0.1))+ #formatting to make it look nicer
  geom_text(stat = "stratum",
            aes(label = after_stat(stratum)), fontface="bold") + 
  geom_flow()+
  geom_text(stat="flow", aes(label=percent), nudge_x = 0.5, fontface="bold", size=5)+
  theme_void()+
  guides(fill=guide_legend(title=""))+#modify title of legend
  ggtitle("Future Plans of Nurses Intending to Leave\n Current Position Within Next Year" )+
  theme(plot.title=element_text(hjust=0.5, face="bold", size=15), 
        legend.position = "none")#label title and axes & suppress legend
```

And here is my dataframe:

```
survey_3<-data.frame(leave=c("Plans to leave w/in 6 months or a year",
                                  "Plans to leave w/in 6 months or a year",
                                  "Plans to leave w/in 6 months or a year",
                                  "Plans to leave w/in 6 months or a year",
                                  "Plans to leave w/in 6 months or a year"),
                     Q58=c("I plan to pursue additional education",
                           "I plan to take a non-nursing position",
                           "I plan to take another nursing position in my current institution",
                           "I plan to retire/stop working",
                           "I plan to take another nursing position outside of my current institution"),
                     freq=c(139, 299, 307, 514, 957),
                     percent=c("1.97%", "4.24%", "4.35%", "7.28%", "13.56%"))
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The issue is that you get a label for each axis. One option to fix that would be to add your labels using `stat="identity"` which requires to map a  value on `x`, i.e. `x = 1.5`.

```r
p +
  geom_text(
    aes(
      x = 1.5,
      label = percent
    ),
    position = position_stack(vjust = .5),
    fontface = "bold"
  )
```

[image]

A second option would be to use `coord_cartesian` to set the limits to hide the duplicated label:

```r
p +
  geom_text(
    stat = "flow", aes(
      label = percent
    ),
    nudge_x = 0.5,
    fontface = "bold"
  ) +
  coord_cartesian(xlim = c(1, 2))
```

[image]

**base plot**

```
library(ggplot2)
library(ggalluvial)

p <- ggplot(
  data = survey_3,
  aes(axis1 = leave, axis2 = stringr::str_wrap(Q58, 40), y = freq)
) +
  geom_alluvium(aes(fill = Q58)) +
  geom_stratum() +
  scale_x_discrete(limits = c("leave", "Q58"), expand = c(0.1, 0.1)) +
  geom_text(
    stat = "stratum",
    aes(
      label = after_stat(stratum)
    ), fontface = "bold"
  ) +
  geom_flow() +
  theme_void() +
  guides(fill = guide_legend(title = "")) + # modify title of legend
  ggtitle("Future Plans of Nurses Intending to Leave\n Current Position Within Next Year") +
  theme(
    plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0.5, face = "bold", size = 15),
    legend.position = "none"
  )
```